# Windows task scheduler to run SQL query and save output

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks, bcp

I have a working but relatively verbose SQL script, which I want to run every night and save the results in a csv file. The SQL Server job scheduler, my preferred approach, seems unable to save the query results to a file. I also tried scheduling a task with Windows task scheduler and the following `bcp` command:

```
bcp "MY QUERY HERE" queryout C:\path\to\Desktop\RTFS.txt -c -d servername -U uname -P password
```

The connection times out on the `bcp`. I know SQL Server is accepting remote connections because I can connect to it from a Linux server on the network and accomplish everything I want to in Python. Regrettably though I've been told this must be a Windows-only solution so I can't use the working Python/Linux implementation.

Is there a way either to save output as a file from a SQL Server job or to accomplish the same result with task schedular?

Comment: I suspect you mean SQL Server Agent. The agent doesn't save anything to a file, it's the command you execute that exports the data. If there is no file, then the command has failed. You should configure both your job and the `bcp` call to record any errors.

Comment: BTW are you sure you get a connection, not a command tiemout?Connection timeouts typically mean you've used the wrong server name. The agent service typically runs on the same machine as the database so network issues are out of the question. So are firewall issues - you'd get a rejection immediatelly. If you are getting a command timeout it's because the job takes too long

Comment: @TabAlleman no, unfortunately.

Comment: @TabAlleman The SSIS bulk export taks is essentially bcp, with a graphic interface that prevents you from messing up with the parameters. If it works, so should `bcp`

Comment: You could use the Import/Export Wizard.  At the end, you're given the option to save the task as a DTS file (i.e., what SSIS used to be called), which you can then call through SQL Agent.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes it's `Login timeout expired`. Would using the server's IP address be a useful test?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use [osql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806.aspx) with options -Q "your query" and -o "output file". I think osql is installed as part of ms sql server [express] ...

Answer (score 0):

My solution, which may not be the only or best one, was ultimately to write a C# console application that did what I wanted and then run that from Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your parameters is incorrect in your command line.
the parameters you want are [-S server name] [-d database name]  [-U username] [-P password]

bcp usage

```
usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
  [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
  [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
  [-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
  [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
  [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
  [-h "load hints"]         [-x generate xml format file]
  [-d database name]        [-K application intent]
```

You are missing the -S tag. 
You are specifying server on the database tag
Also, with -c I think you're suppose to specify the character type you want... just remove the -c and check if the default works for you. 
Can you try the following?

```
bcp "MY QUERY HERE" queryout C:\path\to\Desktop\RTFS.txt -S servername -d database -U uname -P password
```